# Multicast: client can receive but not send

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I've been banging my head against the wall for quite a while now but I can't find a solution or a hint - and I even do not know if my problem is related to programming or external influences.

Based on this tutorial http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/ I have a multicast sender and a multicast receiver. This works like a charm on most computers but on some computers only the receiver works.

Example:

Situation 1:

Client A starts the sender

Client B starts the receiver & receives packets -> all fine

Client C (for reference) starts the receiver & receives packets -> all fine

Situation 2:

Client B starts the sender

Client A starts the receiver & nothing happens :-(

Client C (for reference) starts the receiver & nothing happens :-(

For some reason, Client B can receive multicast packets but when sending multicast packets they get lost somewhere. I've done all I can imagine: firewalls are deactivated, I deactivated almost all options on the networking adapter like 'UDP dumping' and so on (Realtek PCIe GBE Familiy Controller) and I even used an other switch (D-Link unmanaged instead of Netgear managed).
Windows' resource monitor also shows network acitivity, so that multicast sender does really send something out.

Can anybody give a hint on how I could at least get closer to the root of the problem? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Ah well, I forgot to mention: loopback works fine! If Client B starts sender and receiver it works.

Comment: Ok, I modified the program to show how many bytes are sent and now I'm sure it sends the data out. I also used Wireshark to capture the packets and Wireshark shows the same output on all clients: the data is being sent. Now, I am completely lost: two clients on the same switch, both seem to send, but only one can really send, the other client's packets disappear... I think I'll have to investigate further and I assume this problem is not related to programming...

Comment: Have you solved this? It seems very similar to a problem I'm having.